# Flutter Want to navigate to google maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I have a set of locations. Starting point > Mid Point > Ending Point.
I want to create a button in which when the user presses the button it will redirect the user to the actual google maps direction and it should set the direction automatically on google maps.
how can I make it work?

Comment: You can use the [Directions URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started?authuser=0#directions-action) for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `url_launcher` package and set latitudeopen and longitude of origin and destination location, then open this url

https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=currentLatitude,currentLongitude&daddr=destLatitude,destLongitude

Url example :

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=41.3999625,2.1958264&daddr=41.3942644,2.1885308

example:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
...    
GestureDetector(
       onTap: ()=> launch('http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=41.3999625,2.1958264&daddr=41.3942644,2.1885308'),
       child: Text('open map'),
    )
...
```